# Using a global object in Nodejs vs Redis hash

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, redis, heap-memory

I intend to use nodejs on server - 12 cores, 64 GB RAM.

If I have an object like so -

```
obj= {x1: [user1_id, user2_id, user4_id, user89_id, user541_id],
      x2: [user55_id, user44_id, user3_id, user89_id, user132_id],
      .... }
```

**Question**: At what point does it make sense to store obj as a Redis hash rather than in a global object in Nodejs? 
(At scale, I expect to have ~300,000 keys with an average of 5 elements each) 
(Persistence of obj is not an issue)

**Question**: What is allowed as maximum heap size of a Nodejs process?

Comment: If you will want to use nodejs clustering to make use of the 12 cores, then you will want to use redis so multiple clustered processes can all access the data.  Using redis will also help you with nodejs memory usage since you'd be moving the redis storage to another process and out of the nodejs process.

Comment: If I use cluster.fork() inside the main server process, will global variables not be accessible inside forked processes?

Comment: Globals are not shared among node.js clustered processes or shared with any other process for that matter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are some reasons to move to redis:

1. If you want to cluster your node.js process to take advantage of multiple cores for handling high load.  Global variables in node.js are not shared among clustered processes so you would need the data to be managed by another process (redis) which each node.js cluster could access.
2. If you are concerned about large memory use within node.js.  Moving to redis moves the memory used by the data out of the node.js process.
3. If you want some of the data management or other features of redis.

Per [this article](http://prestonparry.com/articles/IncreaseNodeJSMemorySize/), you can dial up the allowed memory usage of node.js pretty far (from a default memory cap of 1.76GB up to 26GB).